# Why is an instance of my class seen as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Just a quick question. I have a test specification that looks like so...

```
require 'user'

describe "Integration" do
  let(:user) { User.new(voucher) }

  context 'no voucher' do
    let(:voucher) { nil }
context 'no voucher' do
let(:voucher) { nil }

    it 'should bill default price all the time' do
        user.bill
        expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 6.95
        ... ...
    end
  end

  context 'vouchers' do
    describe 'default vouchers' do
      let(:voucher) { Voucher.create(:default, credit: 15) }

      it 'should not bill user if has a remaining credit' do
        user.bill
        expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 0.0
        ... ...
      end
    end
```

I have a very simple voucher class atm

```
class Voucher
    attr_accessor :credit, :type

    def self.create(type, *attrs)
        @type = type
    end

    def billed_for
        Random.new.rand(0..4)
    end
end
```

Now what's weird is If I try to access the variables of the voucher class through user where it's stored it throws up and undefined variable. The object definitely isn't nil, when I check the type it tells me it's an array! Printing this produces stuff like...
    [{:credit=>15}][{:discount=>50, :number=>3}]
Why is this happening? Have I set something wrong in my user class? My user class is below

```
require 'order'
require 'voucher'

class User
    attr_accessor :voucher, :orders

    def initialize(voucher = nil, orders =[])
        @orders = orders
        @voucher = voucher.nil? ? nil : voucher
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your voucher.create method isn't actually creating a voucher. If you check the class of the return result of `Voucher.create`, you should see `Symbol`:

```
Voucher.create(:default).class #=> Symbol
```

This is because you're returning the result of setting `@type = type`, where type is `:default`, which has a class of `Symbol`. I'm not sure where the array is coming from, but in order to create a proper Voucher, you should override the initialize method, much like you're doing in the `User` class:

```
class Voucher
  def initialize(type, *attrs)
    @type = type
    # you should probably do something with attrs as well.
  end
end
```

Now you can call `Voucher.new` to build an initialized Voucher object:

```
Voucher.new(:default).class #=> Voucher
```

If you want to keep the same api, you can then define self.create as follows:

```
class Voucher
  def self.create(type, *attrs)
    new(type, *attrs)
  end
end

Voucher.create(:default, :some, :more, :attrs).class #=> Voucher
```

As an aside, you don't really need that nil check in the initialize method of your `User` class, the following is equivalent:

```
class User
  def initialize(voucher = nil, orders =[])
    @orders = orders
    @voucher = voucher
  end
end
```

---

Looking at your tests, Voucher's create method takes two parameters, a voucher type and an attributes hash.

```
Voucher.create(:default, credit: 15, discount: 50)
```

is equivalent to

```
Voucher.create(:default, { credit: 15, discount: 50 })
```

so you probably want to define Voucher's initialize method as follows:

```
class Voucher
  def initialize(type, attrs = {})
    @type = type
    # iterate through the attributes hash and assign attributes appropriately 
  end
end
```

Assuming you have defined setters for each of the attribute keys you are assigning, you could do the following:

```
def initialize(type, attrs = {})
  @type = type
  attrs.each do |key, value|
    send("#{key}=", value) 
  end
end
```

See documentation of send [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send).

Given the following line of code:

```
Voucher.new(:default, credit: 15, discount: 50)
```

The following logic would happen inside the voucher's initialize function:

```
@type = :default
# iterate through the hash { credit: 15, discount: 50 }
self.credit=(15)   # equivalent to self.credit = 15
self.discount=(50) # equivalent to self.discount = 50
```

and you wind up with a properly initialized voucher object.

It is straightforward to modify your create method appropriately.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I can't change the test specs as they're part of the unchangable example. And I have to use the factory method pattern with the voucher class. Further more I have to pass the voucher class in from the test.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on the self.create you were showing?
I get I was returning the wrong information, this should've been create a new instance of the class like you've done. How would I then go about looping through the attrs array and assigning these to variables?

Comment: Thank you so much for expanding that's really cleared a lot up.
I'm trying to set the options hash to variables now but I'm not getting anything. Using the send method like you showed throws up an undefined method error. After doing a little research I implemented the instance_variable_set method like so 
`instance_variable_set("@#{subkey}", subvalue)` this isn't throwing up any errors but if try and call a variable set( `@credit`, `self.credit`, `credit`) by it in another method it's empty. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: looks like I just had to add the instance of the class to the method and it did it! `thing.instance_variable_set("@#{key}".to_sym, subvalue)`